# Rome to Paris by train

Tags: trains, france, italy, paris, rome

Can anyone tell me how can I book Rome to Paris train ticket? I am trying
[Trenitalia website](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=ad1ce14114bc9110VgnVCM10000080a3e90aRCRD)
but not getting any results.

I want the fastest train, preferably running during the daytime.

Also, can any one tell me how many days in advance is booking usually required before ticket becomes unavailable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Hafas sites (I used the [Belgian](http://hafas.bene-system.com/) one), I found 10h41 with one change at Torino:

- EuroStar Italia - [ES 9630](http://hafas.bene-system.com/bin/traininfo.exe/en/953295/419800/416404/109563/684/L=profi): Roma Termini (13h00) to Torino Porta Susa (16h52)
- TGV - [TGV 9248](http://hafas.bene-system.com/bin/traininfo.exe/en/59187/127857/711260/335901/684/L=profi): Torino Porta Susa (17h35) to Paris Austerlitz, (23h51)

I got a quote on [voyages-sncf.com](http://www.voyages-sncf.com/), the french railways company: 208€ in 2nd class and 262€ in first class. For such a trip, the added comfort justifies the price difference and first class is less likely to be full, so you can book as late as one hour before departure.

Comment: Seems kind of expensive if the only reason to get the train is travelling from A to B. I get price quotes for one-way direct flights day after tomorrow starting from 70 EUR.

Comment: @mindcorrosive: On this particular trip, flight is cheaper. But usually, for a fair comparison, you have to add hidden costs such as luggage and transportation between downtown and airports.

Comment: Train travel is not a synonym for cheap travel. On the other hand, add to the 70 Euros the price to get from the airports to the city center. There might also be other fees, such as a fee to  check in luggage. Then you get closer. Moreover if this is a Ryanair flight, you will arrive in Beauvais, some 90 km from the center of Paris

Comment: First, train is expensive if you book at the last moment, and for international travel (booking in almost 3 months, I found a ticket for 160 euros). You can try https://www.thello.com/, a private company that runs night trains, with prices around 80-100 euros with a basic search.

Comment: @mindcorrosive, you don't have to queue and wait 1h+ for security on train either.

Comment: Note, according to voyages-sncf.com, the second train actually arrives at 23h19, which makes total journey time 10h19. Even better! (Found via [Swiss](http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/bin/query.exe/fn?REQ0JourneyStopsS0G=rome&REQ0JourneyStopsS0A=7&REQ0JourneyStopsZ0G=paris&REQ0JourneyStopsZ0A=7&start=%BB+Chercher+correspondances) trains site!)

Comment: @Benjol: Even with 1h wait at security (which is excessive), a 1h layover and include airport transfer, you'd still save at least three to four hours, and probably a good chunk of money. Don't get me wrong, I am a great fan of trains and love looking through the window, just for this segment it doesn't make much sense if the only purpose is getting from Rome to Paris, especially during daytime as the OP prefers.

Comment: This is, of course, why SNCF and Trenitalia are digging a giant tunnel through a mountain to lower this journey time.  Rome-Paris should be about six hours on a direct train once the Mont d'Ambin tunnel is complete - surprisingly competitive with flying.

Answer (score 9):

You can book this train on **my** website, loco2.com:

http://loco2.com/journey/rome-paris-1q0w3dk

Unfortunately we can currently only ship this ticket to a UK address.

If you cannot book elsewhere, I would recommend trying http://raileurope-world.com as they ship globally.

Comment: I would buy it directly from the trsin company. It's straightforward and you receive it immediately, wherever you live. Not need to use (and pay) a middle man

Comment: We don't charge any booking fees so it is the same price as booking direct. We are trying to make it easier to book trains, not add costs. Raileurope-world.com is owned by SNCF (one of the companies that runs trains on this route) so that's why I recommended it. Our website loco2.com is integrated directly with the Rail Europe/SNCF booking system and the prices offered are generally the same (however there are some complexities added by the currency exchange policies applied by SNCF).

Comment: For this route we can offer a price of £116, which is cheaper than the €208 quoted in the original answer to the question. So we are definitely not adding costs, as the down vote implies.

Comment: The negative vote was for the ad. I have nothing against ads, but they should be clearly identifiable as such. This one is hidden as an answer to a question.

Comment: Disagree with the downvote. It's not hidden, but the answer clearly states *my website*. Therefore it's clear that there is a potential conflict of interest. However, subsequent answers are more complete.

Comment: Thanks gerrit. I identified it as my website, and am always impartial in my recommendations. I only recommended my site because the user was having an issue with Trenitalia and I know the ticket can be booked on my site. I also recommended a competitors' website, and explained that they offer international delivery.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [www.tgv-europe.com](http://www.tgv-europe.com) to book the train tickets. According to the schedule there, the fastest train takes 10:09, with one change in Torino, Italy. However, there are also some direct trains, but all of them are slower.

The price depends a little bit on your country of residence, but it seems to be around 200€ for a one-way ticket in the 2nd class.

Comment: Booking further in advance may even decrease the price to €115 (single/1 person/2nd class)

Answer (score 4):

I think there will be almost always available tickets, but the price will be high.
If you can buy a lot in advance, you will have the lower prices:
Roma - Milano : from 19 €, 3 h, max 4 months in advance, http://trenitalia.com
Milano - Paris : from 29 €, 7 h, max 3 months in advance, http://voyages-sncf.com

If i look in one month, around 22 feb, it will be around 50 + 50 €, when an all-in-one Paris - Roma ticket is around 150-200 €.

The train from Roma arrives in Milano Centrale and the one going to Paris leaves from Milano Garibaldi.

(Is there a reason you don't consider the plane?)